# very weird:applescript works fine on ScriptEditor but when saved to app, didn't work

Tags: macos, applescript

I want to turn on and off my shadowsocks client easier. So after some searching I have written code like this.

```
ignoring application responses
    tell application "System Events" to tell process "Shadowsocks"
        click menu bar item 1 of menu bar 1
    end tell
end ignoring
do shell script "killall System\\ Events"
delay 0.0
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Shadowsocks"
    tell menu bar item 1 of menu bar 1
        click menu item 2 of menu 1
    end tell
end tell
```

This works fines mostly time. The case is that after a while you don't run this script, the ScriptEditor will tell me can not find the menu item. Just after that, click another time, it will work and will work for a pretty much time. And when I saved this script file to application, it will display this error message.

```
Can't get <<class menE>> 1 of <<class mbri>> 1 of 
<<class mbar>> 1 of <<class prcs>> "Shadowsocks" 
of application "System Events". Invalid Index.
System Events got an error: Can't get menu 1 of 
menu bar item 1 of menu bar 1 of process "Shado
wsocks". Invalid index. (-1719)
```

[This is the UI Browser's result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDr4j.png)

Comment: What is the purpose of killing System Events?

Comment: So you've tried `tell application "Shadowsocks" to quit` and `tell application "Shadowsocks" to activate` `tell application "Shadowsocks" to launch`? Do these work to quit and launch the app? If so, you should use this method and dispense with using System Events. To see if Shadowsocks is running, you can use the Finder: `tell application "Finder" to set itsUp to "Shadowsocks" is in name of processes`

Comment: Actually I don't know, I write these code from a model on the stackoverflow. I have tested if I don't write like, this code will execute about 5 seconds or more which is unacceptable.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

thanks for everyone's contribution. I have done this job by another way. I just download another version of ss -- ShadowsocksX-NG. Then I set it to Manual Mode, after that, I just need to write some code to change the proxy settings of my computer.
And I have upload this to the github(https://github.com/dvstter/Change-Mac-Proxy-Setting-With-Alfred). If anybody needs the same demand, please go to there to see something.
BTW I am a Chinese, so there may be some problems in my English.
At last, I want to thank you again. All of you. Sincerely!!!

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in the latest version of Sierra and [ShadowsocksX-NG](https://github.com/shadowsocks/ShadowsocksX-NG/releases/tag/v1.7.0).

```
clickOn() --  This runs the actions to click "Turn Shadowsocks On"

--  This is the handler to click "Turn Shadowsocks On"
on clickOn()
    tell application "ShadowsocksX-NG" to activate
    delay 0.3 -- Adjust if necessary
    tell application "System Events"
        click menu bar item 1 of menu bar 1 of application process "ShadowsocksX-NG"
        delay 0.1 -- Adjust if necessary
        try
            click menu item "Turn Shadowsocks On" of menu 1 of menu bar item 1 of menu bar 1 of application process "ShadowsocksX-NG"
        end try
    end tell
end clickOn
```

---

```
clickOff()  --  This runs the actions to click "Turn Shadowsocks Off"

--  This is the handler to click "Turn Shadowsocks Off"
on clickOff()
    tell application "ShadowsocksX-NG" to activate
    delay 0.1 -- Adjust if necessary
    tell application "System Events"
        click menu bar item 1 of menu bar 1 of application process "ShadowsocksX-NG"
        delay 0.1 -- Adjust if necessary
        try
            click menu item "Turn Shadowsocks Off" of menu 1 of menu bar item 1 of menu bar 1 of application process "ShadowsocksX-NG"
        end try
    end tell
end clickOff
```

---

If you simply want to start the application if it is not running or quit the application if it is running...

```
if running of application "ShadowsocksX-NG" then
    tell application "ShadowsocksX-NG" to quit
else
    tell application "ShadowsocksX-NG" to activate
end if
```

Comment: Well, this way just hit my mind, but I think this way needs more code to get the running state of ShadowsocksX-NG. Emm, what I want is to alter the state of ss. That means if it is running, then I need to stop it. Or I need to start it.